# Edit post taxonomy before post will be saved to database

Tags: php, wordpress

**Scenario:** I have a plugin that scraping another website and creating wordpress posts. I can't edit the plugin. But what I want is editting the taxonomy(tags) before it will be saved to the database.

**Code idea:**

```
function taxonomy_edit( $data , $postarr ) {

    // Get tags (array)
    $taxonomies = $data['tags_input'];

        // Here will be some array edit

    // Editted taga (array)
    $data['tags_input'] = $taxonomies;

    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'taxonomy_edit' , 99, 2);
```

Is there a way to edit a taxonomy before saving it to the database for the first time?

Comment: No @Lukas that's not feasible

Comment: It can be achieved, in case we edit the plugin you are using

Comment: *I can't edit the plugin.* why?

Comment: @GetSet - editing plugins directly is considered a bad, if not one of the worst, practices available. Unless you fork it and start merging the official trunk into your version, which is more hassle than it's worth 99.99% of the time.

Comment: @Lukas Rabon, you shouldn't need to edit the terms *before* they're inserted, you could make use of [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/) when the post is created - as it lets you append or overwrite them.

Comment: @Xhynk for a local only solution why would this be bad? With open source clean source (un-minified) this could be a viable way to adapt it to the project.

Comment: It's bad because now you need to keep updating your version of the modified plugin every time there is an update to the plugin. A local solution, perhaps, but then you're still beholden to maintaining your own subversion of the plugin when an update is released if you ever make your website available. WordPress is built with Action Hooks and Filter specifically so you do not need to edit core files, plugin files, or theme files directly.

Answer (score -1):

The better way is to create new taxonomy first when you are importing new post and then assign that post to that taxonomy.